# Wordpress PHP spitting out the same post ID in Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Would anyone know why my code is making my Carousel integration output the same post ID? I tried everything I can but can not figure out what is going on.

I am trying to make it so that my Wordpress theme will output a carousel with "the_post_thumbnail" function. It's working but it repeats the same Post. Any help would be great, I am completely stuck. Thank you.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <?php
        $args_cat = array(
            'include' => '7, 9, 6'
        );
        $categories = get_categories( $args_cat );
        //$categories = get_categories();
        $count = 0;
        //$currentPage = (get_query_var( 'paged' )) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
        $args = array( 'posts_per_page'=> 1 );
        query_posts($args);

        foreach($categories as $category):

            $args = array( 
                'type' => 'post',
                'posts_per_page' => 1,
            );

            $lastBlog = new WP_Query( $args ); 

            if( $lastBlog->have_posts() ):

                while( $lastBlog->have_posts() ): $lastBlog->the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="carousel-item <?php if($count == 0): echo 'active'; endif; ?>">
                    <?php // get_template_part( 'post', get_post_format() ); ?>
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full', ['class' => 'd-block w-100'] ); ?>
                    <?php the_title( sprintf('<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="%s">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ),'</a></h1>' ); ?>
                    <small><?php // the_category(' '); ?></small>
                    </div>

                <?php endwhile;

            endif;

            wp_reset_postdata();

        $count++;

        endforeach;

    ?>
</div>
```

Here is the output (This has been edited to shorten down):

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="/sandbox-theme/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/fb-logo-dark.jpg" class="d-block w-100 wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="/sandbox-theme/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/fb-logo-dark.jpg 180w,>                                        
        <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="https://publifiedlabs.com/sandbox-theme/2017/12/02/test-4/">test 4</a></h1>                                      
        <small></small>
    </div>




    <div class="carousel-item ">
        <img .... >test 4</a></h1>                                      
        <small></small>

    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item ">
        <img ..... >test 4</a></h1>                                     
        <small></small>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make only one change 'post_per_page' should be -1 for all and any other number for many images u want

'posts_per_page' => -1

Comment: Thanks for the help but it was the wrong version of bootstrap causing this issue.

Comment: Disregard my previous comment, your solution solved my problem of repetition posts. Thank you.

Comment: The repetition was solved but it now spits out multiple duplicate 'divs' and multiple of them have the 'active' class on them making a lot of them show at once. Can you check it out for me on the link here: https://publifiedlabs.com/sandbox-theme/

Comment: Before loop starts take a variable $i and initialize it to 0(zero) and when loop is getting closed increment that $i. Now check if $i==0 then put active class and rest of div with only item class not active

Comment: <div class="carousel-inner">

$i = 0;

while( your condition ){

    <div <?php if($i == 0){ ?> class="carousel-item active"  <?php }else{ ?> class="carousel-item"  <?php } ?>> 

     <!--- Rest of your code   -->


    </div>

    $i++;

 }

 </div>

Comment: I was able to get the loop to work but what is happening is it is treating each index as '0' from a blog post that is being displayed. So this makes every post have an 'active' class added to it. Would you know how to increment the index for the blog post?